# Cannot resolve method 'split(java.lang.String)' when using lambda expression

Tags: java, apache-spark, lambda

I am trying to split a String array with a lambda expression. It however tells me that the split method cannot be resolved. I am doing this to parse a Java Spark RDD of type String to double.

```
JavaRDD parsedData = data.map(s -> {
                String[] sarray = s.split(" ");
                double[] values = new double[sarray.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < sarray.length; i++) {
                    values[i] = Double.parseDouble(sarray[i]);
                }
                return Vectors.dense(values);
            });
            parsedData.cache();
```

Comment: Does `data` contain `String`s only?

Comment: Yes, it is an RDD that contains Strings only

Comment: What is the data type of "data"? It has to be Stream<String>, so that the compiler can know that "s" is a String (given that you intend to call java.lang.String.split()).

Comment: Show us the *full* error message, so we can see on which object type you're trying to call `split`.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. It is not directly from type String:
        JavaRDD data = jsc.textFile(path);

Comment: Error:(37, 32) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method split(java.lang.String)
  location: variable s of type java.lang.Object

Comment: [`JavaRDD`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html) is a *generic* class, but you didn't specify the generic type parameters, which means you're using a **raw generic**. *Do not do that!* Always specify the generic type parameters, e.g. `JavaRDD<String>`. --- Because the type parameter was missing, `s` defaults to be an `Object`, which is why `split` is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as said in a comment, data is of type `Stream<Object>`, this code should do the job:

```
JavaRDD parsedData = data.map( o -> o.toString() )
    .map( s -> 
    {
        String[] sarray = s.split( " " );
        double[] values = new double [sarray.length];
        for( int i = 0; i < sarray.length; i++ ) 
        {
            values[i] = Double.parseDouble( sarray[i] );
        }
        return Vectors.dense( values );
    });
    parsedData.cache();
```

Comment: This isn't really an acceptable alternative to using generics correctly.

Comment: @David Conrad: Agreed! But I was lazy and did not look up the definition for `JavaRDD`; instead I took the declaration `Stream<Object> data =…` for granted.